# Парсинг JSON в AJAX из PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

Я новичок в js. Проблема в парсинге json, полученного из PHP в jQuery AJAX. У меня есть форма, данные из нее записываются в БД с использованием AJAX.

Как сделать так, чтобы они сразу же и отображались в таблице под этой формой, уже все перерыл?

**php:**

```
  <?php
  $sql = ("INSERT INTO products (Name, Price) VALUES (:name, :price)");
  $name = trim($_POST["Name"]);
  $price = trim($_POST["Price"]);
  $params = [':name' => $name, ':price' => $price];
  $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  $result = $query->execute($params);
  echo json_encode($result);
  ?>
```

Написал работающий код на ввод данных, а на тестовый вывод в консоль не работает(.done(function(res))

**js:**

```
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ok").on('click', function(){
      var nameValue = $("#name").val();
      var priceValue = $("#price").val();

      $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "Products.php",
        data: { Name: nameValue, Price: priceValue }
      })
      .done(function(res){
        var json = jQuery.parseJSON(res);
        alert(json.answer);
      });
      });
    })
  })
</script>
```

Comment: консоль откройте и ошибки посмотрите.  не надо парсить json, jquery сама это сделает. и что вы ожидаете в в json.answer, если в скрипте вы возвращаете серверу $result булевого типа?

Comment: @teran, пробовал в консоли смотреть, в res вообще нет значений. А с сервера мне надо $params отдавать в json, так? И можно по подробнее про то ,что jquery сама распарсит, не очень понимаю.

Comment: в целом можете вообще  ничего не отдавать. у вас данные уже есть в nameValue,priceValue. отсервера вам в принципе надо узнать, произошла ли вставка данных успешно или нет. JQuery автоматически определяет тип возвращаемого результата, и если видит там Json, то в res вы получите уже объект. Еще проще будет если на серверной стороне вы выдадите header content: applicatino/json

Comment: @teran, мне вот как раз нужно сделать вывод из бд, потому что  мне нужно, чтобы в таблицу записывались все данные из базы, так как они там хранились до ввода новых данных из формы. Тем более, что дальше планирую добавить функционал на удаление и редактирование данных в каждой строке таблицы.

Comment: тогда после вставки надо выбрать в се записи и их вернуть в json, либо сгенерированный html тела таблицы

Comment: @teran, вот как раз я и хочу вернуть это в json из php и сгенерировать таблицу, но с парсингом в jquery проблема. Вы можете по коду подсказать, а то я ничего толкового не нашел?

Comment: в php вы возвращаете результат обработки insert а вам надо вернуть список записей т.е. надо после успешной вставки сделать select и в json_encode вернуть ваш список. А в jquery ajax по моему надо бы сделать так, установить заголовок   dataType: 'json', и не надо будет парсить результат он уже будет json. И да в теории очень правильно было  бы вернуть заголовок в php ответе который должен быть header('Content-Type: application/json');

Comment: @binliz, то есть я должен в функции .done(function(res)) обратиться к методу  $.ajax с заголовком dataType: 'json'?

Comment: в общем в коментарии не получается с кодом просто надо параметр добавить в $.ajax(.... +++dataType:'json' параметры+++.done( function(res)){...}); и у вас будет уже в res json

Answer (score 0):

Примерное выполнение:

1. создать пустой div id="your_div".
2. В новом div описать переменные которые сохраняешь, например `nameValue` переменные PHP с условием `if ($nameValue){}`
3. При сохранении данных в функции .done (успешное сохранение) перезагрузить сам div а не страницу, например так:

   ```
   var url = window.location.href;$("#your_div").load(url + " #your_div");
   ```

P.S. сделай проще - в функции .done задекларируй переменные в js, и вставь их в блок div id="your_div", вот [примерно то, что тебе нужно](https://jsfiddle.net/yarkov_aleksei/bmcwha46/)

Comment: не очень понял 2 пункт, можно поподробнее пожалуйста?

Comment: Не знаю контретно как у тебя хранятся переменные в PHP. Например у меня есть переменная $variable, которая заполняется данными. Если она != null, то показывать div. Вообщем второй пункт необязателен